# Float value changes when inserted into database

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using LINQtoSQL mapper and LINQ in order to insert values into my database (SQL Server 2008 R2). I have 3 layers in my app and when I trace my application on inserting new row, everything goes well. but after checking my database, the value of one field with type float changes. for example when I insert 12.69, in the database the value is 12.6899995803833. I am totally confused and do not know what to do. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Floating point numbers are tricky.  Check out http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/  Particularly the "Don't store that in a float" article.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use `decimal` in C# and `DECIMAL(p,s)` in SQL Server, if you want values you enter (in base 10) to be exactly represented.

The types `float` and `double` in C# (and `REAL` and `FLOAT` in SQL Server) are binary (base 2), and cannot exactly represent many decimal values.  Of course, decimal still has limited precision (fixed in C#, and what you specify in SQL Server).

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a problem where you are changing from one type to another type with more precision.

Comment: More likely the number is just being printed differently. Neither float nor double can actually store 12.69, so in fact the original question is wrong -- the author was *not* inserting 12.69 into the database. Probably the author was inserting the float closest to 12.69, which is more accurately printed as 12.6899995803833.

BTW, the exact value of 12.69f (assuming an IEEE float) is:

    12.68999958038330078125

Anybody who tells you that they have exactly stored 12.69 in a binary floating-point number is mistaken.